# Crystal report individual schedule run for each possible parameter values

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, business-objects

I have a requirement to schedule individual run for a report for each possible database values for the customer parameter. So, if we have 1000 customers in the customer table. The report needs to run an instance for each customer value - i.e a 1000 versions. This needs to happen once a month. Please suggest on ways to accomplish this dynamically.

Comment: Publication can be the solution here, but I guess it will be a lot of work setting up 1000 Profile value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Crystal Report that supplies `id`, `full name`, and `email address` (the names don't need to match):

[image]

Add report to Enterprise.

Create new Publication:

[image]

Select `dynamic recipients`, Crystal Reports, then the report that you published earlier:

[image]

Map the report's fields to the interface:

[image]

Configure `Personalization`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need a data driven reports - run a query and then run a report for each record returned by the query. Check R-Tag (www.r-tag.com). Their scheduler supports data driven reports. They have also a free community edition just for Crystal reports, which may support this feature too.